# How to store all columns of the matrix in Matlab workspace

Tags: matlab, matrix

Sorry for the vague title, but I wasn't sure how to name it properly.

Let's say I have this vector:

```
v=[2 5 8]';
```

Also I have the range of numbers as follow:

```
x=2:4
```

I want to create a for loop that will multiply the vector by 2, then use this newly created vector and multiply it by 3 and then use that and multiply it by 4. What I essentialy want is a 3 by 3 matrix

When I code something like this:

```
v=[2 5 8]';

for i= 2:4
    k=v*i
end
```

This doesn't work because

a) Instead of multiplying by the next number in the loop it just adds the elements to itself i.e( in the second iteration I want (12, 30, 48)' and not (6,15,24)'

b) It doesn't store all 3 sets of values in the workspace.

EDIT

```
for i=1:1:length(x)
       c1=fftshift(fft(u0z));
       c2=exp(-1j*(p^2*x(i)/(2*lamda))).*c1;
       c3=ifft(ifftshift(c2));
       u1=exp(1j*lamda*(n(i)^2-1)*x(i)/2).*c3;
       u0z=u1
    end
```

Edit 2

```
for k=1:1:length(x)
   c1=fftshift(fft(u0z));
   c2=exp(-1j*(p^2*x(k)/(2*lamda))).*c1;
   c3=ifft(ifftshift(c2));
   u1=exp(1j*lamda*(n(k)^2-1)*x(i)/2).*c3;
   u0z=u1;
   mat(:,k)=u0z;
end
```

Comment: you are overwriting your results in each iteration of the loop, you have to assign the result to different indices something like `u0z(i,:)=`. Small tip, you should not use `i` as the looping variable as it also represent complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally did it? Does what you see in Edit 2 make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MATLAB's [`cumprod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html) and implicit expansion (for MATLAB before R2016b, you need [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for that), that's a one-liner:

```matlab
v * cumprod(x)
%  bsxfun(@times, v, cumprod(x))

ans =
     4    12    48
    10    30   120
    16    48   192
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I thought posting too easy example may be difficult to get answer which i really wanted. If you don't mind looking at my edit, the code calculates all u0z for all the iterations, but it only saves the last result in the workspace. Do you mind looking at it and helping me out?